# asp:login no longer shows username as it is entered

Tags: asp.net, .aspxauth

My program starts with asp:login.  It used to show a "suggested" username as I started to enter my username but for some reason stopped doing this.  I have not made any changes to the login (that I am aware of although this could be a rookie oops).  I deleted and re-entered the command but have not been able to get it back to the original state.  Other programs seem to be unaffected.  Does anybody have any suggestions for what I should look at to correct this?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you changed a setting on the browser not to store auto complete entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set on any control this attribute `autocomplete="off"` or set it on the form control, then the browser did not make suggestions from the past.

Comment: Setting autocomplete="on" solved the problem.  Now all I have to do is figure out how it got removed :)

Comment: @BruceSmith If this happens only on one browser, only on your computer, check for the plugins - they may add it.